# Change gtk window state from callback

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, gtk2hs

I have a simple GTK window with menu bar which has `Open` item. It gets filename inside callback of `menuItemActivate`:

```
openPressed = do
    chooser <- fileChooserDialogNew

...
    filename <- performResponse res chooser
        widgetHide chooser
        where
            performResponse ResponseCancel _ = return ("")
            performResponse ResponseOk chooser = do
                Just fname <- fileChooserGetFilename chooser
                putStrLn fname 
                --how can i put filename in label inside MainForm from here?
                return fname
```

How can I put filename to label located in my main window if `openPressed` is not nested in the main function which initialize main window?

Comment: Not familiar with gtk2hs, but can't you just pass the label you want to change as a parameter to `openPressed`, and then use `openPressed label` instead of `openPressed` for your callback?

Comment: @Cubic, openPressed is callback for signal, it is called by signal, not from main.

Comment: Right... but you're setting this to be the callback at some point. Wherever you're doing that, you can just pass `openPressed label` instead of `openPressed`.

Comment: @Cubic, does it mean that i should initialize callback from other function, not in the global scope of file?

Comment: You can still write the callback in the global filescope, just add a parameter and pass it where you're setting the callback.